# Speed up PostgreSQL query that joins a small table with a big table

Tags: postgresql, performance, join

I am trying to find the fastest way to `JOIN` a small table with a big table in PostgreSQL.

Please have a look at the following minimal example that creates a small table with 5.000 rows and a big table with 3.000.000 rows:

```
-- Create small table
CREATE TABLE small_table (
    id INTEGER,
text VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Create big table
CREATE TABLE big_table (
    id INTEGER
);

-- Insert random data into small table (5.000 rows)
INSERT INTO
     small_table (id, text)
SELECT
     generate_series(1, 5000) AS id,
     md5(random()::text) AS text;

-- Insert random data into big table (3.000.000 rows)
INSERT INTO
     big_table (id)
SELECT id FROM
(
     SELECT
           generate_series(1, 3000000),
           floor(random() * 5000) AS id
) random;
```

Now join the tables using the `INTEGER` ids to get the according text from the small table for every entry in the big table:

```
-- Join small table with big table
SELECT big_table.id, small_table.text
FROM big_table
INNER JOIN small_table
ON big_table.id = small_table.id;
```

The `JOIN` takes between 2 and 4 seconds to run.

Here is the execution plan of the query:

```
1. Hash Inner Join (cost=154.5..84679.5 rows=3000000 width=37) (rows=2999394 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (big_table.id = small_table.id)
2.  Seq Scan on public.big_table as big_table (cost=0..43275 rows=3000000 width=4) (rows=3000000 loops=1)
3.  Hash (cost=92..92 rows=5000 width=37) (rows=5000 loops=1)
    Buckets: 8192 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 416 kB
4.    Seq Scan on public.small_table as small_table (cost=0..92 rows=5000 width=37) (rows=5000 loops=1)
```

When a add the timings to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in PGAdmin the query takes way longer. Here is the result including the timings:
[image: Timings]

Here are the statistics per node type:
[image: Statistics per node type]

And here the statistics per relation:
[image: Statistics per relation]

As we can see:

- A Hash Inner Join is used which according to [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/join-strategies-and-performance-in-postgresql/) should already be the best strategy.
- A Seq Scan is used for both tables. From my understanding that is okay because all rows are read anyway. Creating an index on `id` in both tables still leads to a seq scan.
- Only 416 kB of memory are used so changing `work_mem` should not have an effect.

Please correct me if any of my assumptions and conclusions are wrong.

**So my question is:** What else can be done to speed up the query? Is it even possible or am I hitting the limits of PostgreSQL or an on-disc SQL database in general?

*EDIT*:
[Here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/1jLu#html) is the result of `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose, timing)`. And [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/8PJh) the same with a forced `merge_join`.

Comment: Please show us the complete and **unaltered** execution plan. You have removed some important information (mainly the runtime) and also the indention is a bit messed up

Comment: When I create indexes on the two join columns (Postgres 14), I get this plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/1OIG

Comment: Your tables should have a Primary Key. Without it, a table is meaningless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I added some more information including the timings. Regarding the indention: I just copied the style that PGAdmin uses. Your result with indexes is interesting. When I create indexes nothing changes. And when I switch off ```enable_hashjoin``` and ```enable_nestloop``` to force a ```merge_join``` like in your result, the query takes even longer (> 6 secs). @wildplasser: Setting primary keys on both tables did not change anything.

Comment: Execution plans are better provided as (unaltered) formatted **text** not screen shots, or shared e.g. through https://explain.depesz.com/ And it should be generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` or even `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose, timing)`.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry, I was not familiar with explain.depesz.com. I added links to the bottom of my question. I am still using PostgreSQL 12. But a colleague installed a clean version of PostgreSQL 14 and the query still takes > 3 seconds without indexes. I will ask him to try with indexes. Maybe my installation of PostgreSQL is messed up. I will also try a clean installation of PostgreSQL 14 on my machine.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: I only insert the ```id``` in the big table from the inner ```SELECT``` that has two columns. One for creating 3.000.000 rows via ```generate_series()``` and one for creating a random ```id``` between 0 and 5000. That random ```id``` goes into the single column of ```big_table```.

Comment: "When a add the timings to EXPLAIN ANALYZE in PGAdmin the query takes way longer"  This suggests that your server has very slow user access to the clock because it requires a kernel context switch for each one.  This is a problem which should have been fixed on modern hardware with modern kernels.  That the query without timing takes 2 to 4 second also suggests that your hardware is inadequate, I get 1 second on a cheap laptop.

Answer (score 1):

That is already running as efficiently as possible, and there is no possible improvement.  The way your data are, you need all rows from both tables, so the sequential scans required by the hash join are the most efficient way to do it.

The only possible way to improve on the speed is to see that the sequential scans don't need to access the disk. That is, you need to have enough RAM to keep both tables cached. Then PostgreSQL will effectively act as an in-memory database.

Processing may be slower initially, until all data are in cache. You can improve on that by pre-warming the cache: the `pg_prewarm` standard extension allows you to load both tables in cache.